# Windows batch file, use the "|" (OR) character

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I'm trying to work on a batch script for windows (.bat) that executes some commands, and need to send the '|' character as a parameter. Here's an example:

```
echo hello|world
```

this will never return the `hello|world` string.. I tried to escape it using `hello\|world`, but still no success. How to fix this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo hello^|world
```

In batch you can use carets or double quotes to escape special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the solution.

echo `Hello^|World`